# SSO in .Net core mvc and .Net standard mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, owin, identity

- I have third party SSO to implement in Two of my companies legacy system's.
- One is in .Net standard MVC while second is in .Net core MVC. I have successfully implemented the SSO on .Net core app using **services.AddOAuth()** but I cann't find proper resources to do same in Standard MVC app.
- Here is my implementation snapshot of .Net core app.

[image]

**The problem:**

- Now when I tries to implement same in Standard MVC app, I'm not able to find proper resources for that or at least I have no idea how to proceed.
- The document suggests that first I have to call `/oauth/authorize` which will give me **Comapany Login page and after successful login, system will give me access code to redirectUrl** and then after I have to call `/oauth/token`.
- **I thought of using RestClient or Httpclient to get access code but without using company login page, I can't get it and that's a big blocker for me at the moment.**

What I tried so far?

- I tried to add `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` on `StartUp.Auth` class but it's not working as expected.
- I'm not sure how to validate and login user and how to grab the
  acccess code and pass it to token call. in .Net core services done
  this all automatically but not sure how this will be done in .Net standard app.
- **Is it possible to create a seperate project in .Net core along with MVC 5 and have all the SSO related code there? (since .Net core code works)**
- I have also followed this threads but no luck.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on
- https://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/token-based-authentication-using-Asp-Net-web-api-owin-and-i/

**Any help or clue or idea will be really appreciated. Thanks!**

**EDIT - 1**

- I have used `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` and I'm able to retrieve the access code but still not able to figure out how to get token. tried various ways including TokenClient, MsalAppBuilder etc but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you post code example with `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` usage?

Comment: legacy as in .net framework? you should look for resources around this then. 
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc" might be helpful. PS there is no such thing as ".Net standard MVC" , .net 4.7.2 -4.8.0 and below is known as .net framework. .net core come out and come out with a middle level which exposes some core system api's which is .net standard. .net standard as a stand alone can not mvc. Identity the package you are using in .net core....
`services.AddOAuth()` then check if that is available in .net framework.

Comment: If not available and you have not setup DI in the older framework, then you will have to research older packages.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a seperate project in .Net core along with MVC 5 and have all the SSO related code there? (since .Net core code works)" you can not mix mvc 5 and .net core... they are not compatable. so...if im understand your question correct then NO u can not mix them. (.net framework) and (.net core - 6) are not compatible. you can have stuff in a seperate .net standard which you can share between the two, but that provided there are packages compatible with .net standard.

Comment: I'll update the question with new changes sortly.